# Installing angular-cli on a build agent

Tags: teamcity, angular-cli

I am trying to build an angular-cli app using TeamCity (2017.2.3) on Windows Server, which is configured with two build agents (also running on Windows Server). Both build agents run under dedicated service accounts.

I logged into both build agents as myself, opened an elevated command prompt, and installed angular-cli with `npm install -g @angular/cli` then rebooted each agent. Logging back in again, I can successfully run ng --version.

However, when the build agents are running the build which includes calling `ng build` as part of its build process, the build fails with the error `'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`, and if I check the folder `C:\Users\<service_account>\AppData\Roaming\npm`, there is no reference to `ng`, whereas `C:\Users\<david.keaveny>\AppData\Roaming\npm` contains the `ng` executable.

So how can I install angular-cli so that my service account has access to it?

Comment: Try this:

npm install -g "@angular/cli"

Answer (score 1):

You've installed it as yourself, but your agent is running as the service account.

They won't have access to each other env variables, you can either install it using the service account, or at the start of the build job, update the path variables with the location of ng. e.g. step 1, script path=%path%;location of ng

Answer (score 0):

This is command how to find executable path in windows

```
where.exe ng
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\*[UserName]*\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\ng
C:\Users\*[UserName]*\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\ng.cmd
```